# Silly question on trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

[image: The question]

So, the question was about finding the range of $\cos(2\sin x)$.

He said that the range of $2\sin(x)$ is from $-2 \to 2$ which is quite easy to understand. Then he went on to draw the circle saying that the value of $\cos2$ is in the second quadrant and the value of $\cos(-2)$ is in the fourth quadrant.

Then, he marked the range of $\cos[-2,2]$ in the figure with red. But, why did he mark the right side only? Why didn't he mark the left side of the circle?

Any sort of help is much appreciated! Thanks a ton in advance!

Comment: talking about the range wont make sense until you specify the domain.

Comment: But, that is specified @abel

Comment: Why should he ? What is the meaning of the pink corrugated line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember what the question is asking: find the range of $\cos(2\sin(x))$. Thus you first finds the range of $2\sin(x)$. The range of this then becomes the domain of $\cos$, so we may only plug values from $[-2,2]$ into $\cos$. The whole circle is $2\pi$, which is about $6$, so we only get a fraction of the circle as our range, specifically the fraction which is shaded.

Comment: Why not the left fraction then?

Comment: @Abhishekstudent well it is only going to be one of the two parts, right. So then we know that $0\in[-2,2]$, so it must be the right since that is where $\cos(0)$ is.

Comment: I think I got it now. So, the minimum value is -128radian and the max is 128. So, we are moving from lower limit to the upper limit. This starts from -128 and then goes -125 like this upto given mark

Comment: @Abhishekstudent that sounds right, except you mean degrees, not radians. Also your life will be a lot better if you use radians.

Answer (score 2):

The  image shows the unit circle, so from which you get the $\cos$ function as a projection on the $x$-axis.
In the picture the range of $\cos[-2,2]$ is visualized by the the points on the unit circle with an angle in $[-2,2]$ to the "right side" of the $x$-axis, i.e. a polar coordinate in $[-2,2]$.
This is exaclty the purple arc.

The left side would be the points on the unit circle with polar coordinate in $[2,\pi] \cup [-\pi,-2]$, which is equivalent to the points with polar coordinate in $[2, 2\pi -2$].

Comment: Thanks for the kind help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad I could help